# In how many ways can we color the edges of a tetrahedron with black and red colors?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutation-cycles, polya-counting-theory

Task: In how many ways can we color the edges of a tetrahedron with black and red colors?

I have a problem because I computed the cycle index, considering the rotations of the tetrahedron based on its edges, and obtained: $Z(G,x_1,x_2,x_3)=\frac{1}{12}(x_1^6+8x_3^2+3x_1^2x_2^2)$ or $Z(G,2,2,2)=12$, so the answer is 12.

Then I thought like this: if I label the tetrahedron based on its edges and observe its neighbors (adjacent edges), I get exactly an octahedron, which has a cycle index: $Z(G,x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=\frac{1}{24}(x_1^6+6x_1^2x_4+3x_1^2x_2^2+6x_2^3+8x_3^2)$ or $Z(G,2,2,2,2)=10\neq 12$.

**So what is correct and where is the mistake?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

12 is the right answer. The edges of tetrahedron "transform" to vertices of octahedron, which builds bijection. However, bijection is simply not enough. Take a look at those pictures:[Tetrahedrons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrp6D.png) [Octahedrons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jN1LO.png)

There are only 12 different ways to color vertices of tetrahedron. Bijection transforms them into the following octahedrons. However, there are 2 pairs of the same graph for octahedrons.